# After upgrading to Windows 10 Anniversary Edition the lock screen remains black

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1607, lock-screen

After I recently upgraded to Windows 10 Anniversary Edition I've noticed that the lock screen remains black instead of displaying a picture.

[image: Lock screen image]

As soon as I enter Alt+Ctrl+Del and the login screen appears the background picture also reappears.  However as soon as I go back to the lock screen it returns to a black screen.  Before I installed the Anniversary Edition update the lock screen also had a background image.  Not a big issue but just curious as to why this has now changed and what is required to resolve it?

Windows functions normally and I am able to login without issue, just curious as to why the background image now doesn't display.

Comment: Have you tried to simply change what picture is used, my guess, Windows can't find the picture you have selected.

Comment: Agreed, the target background probably is not found. Try putting it back again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the image back on the lock screen by disabling "Show lock screen background picture on the sign-in screen" in Settings. This, however, doesn't restore the original functionality of having the same image used for both the lock screen and the login screen.

Comment: Yes, I tried this and it also worked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem

### Source: Windows Insider Feedback Hub

[image]

Even they have not solved it but, **Refreshing Your PC might help you.**

> Link:
>   feedback-hub:?contextid=66&feedbackid=66d616d9-966b-4728-9768-a2065ba31a75&form=1&src=2

Comment: Tell me if this is not working, I'll Remove It.

Comment: Link: feedback-hub:?contextid=66&feedbackid=66d616d9-966b-4728-9768-a2065ba31a75&form=1&src=2

Comment: Thanks Karthik, I've played around with both the lock screen settings and also changed the mode so that it always defaults to desktop mode but unfortunately problem still persists.

Comment: I've mentioned that Refreshing your PC might help you

Comment: If I have to refresh my PC to fix I'll live with the problem, definitely not a show stopper.